# handling sign-up in friend / compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

I am having trouble figuring out how to sign up users using cemerick/friend. I can authenticate users with my login method and sign them up via a sign-up route, however, I am unsure how to sign them in once they've signed up.

I tried the following but to no avail.

```
(POST "/sign-up" {params :params} (sign-up-handler params))

(defn sign-up-handler [r]
  (let [user (create (:username r) (:password r))]
    (workflows/make-auth user)
    (ring.util.response/redirect "/")))
```

Comment: To me its not clear what exactly fails. First you say that you cannot "sign up" and then in the second sentence you say that you can "sign up" using the same words. Please be more exact about what is working and what not.

Comment: By sign up,  I mean I am able to add a user record to the database. The user can then navigate to /login after "signing up" and re-use those credentials. I want the backend to log them in upon sign up. I am looking for a way to sign the user in.

Comment: I handled this by doing an ajax sign-up, getting response, on success and posting to /sign-in... It works fine.

Comment: Hm, that looks like a hack to me. Maybe you could call the bcrypt-credential-fn function directly passing in the username / password and a map with the expected credentials?